# Should a subordinate clause be separated if it interrupts main clause?

Tags: punctuation, subordinate-clauses, restrictive-clauses

Should the clause "we provide" be separated by commas if it interrupts the main verb-phrase "your use constitutes"?

> Your use of the Services, we provide, constitutes the subject-matter of the contract.

vs.

> Your use of the Services we provide constitutes the subject-matter of the contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Your use of the [Services (that) **we provide**] constitutes the subject-matter of the contract.

No, you should not separate "we provide" by commas, because it is a [restrictive relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Restrictive_and_non-restrictive). It is too tightly bound with the word "services".

You can separate by commas a non-restrictive relative clause - a clause that provides additional information:

> Your use of the Services, which we provide to anyone who needs them, constitutes the subject matter of the contract.

In this example, it is implied that the reader knowns what the services are and therefore the part between the commas could be omitted: it is merely a "comment".

Moreover, in English only a [restrictive relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Restrictive_or_non-restrictive_relative_clauses) (that uses no commas) can have its [relative pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun) ("**that** we provide") omitted:

> Your use of the Services, we provide to anyone who needs them, constitutes the subject matter of the contract. (WRONG: you need to use the relative pronoun **which**, because the relative clause is non-restrictive)

You can theoretically add the relative pronoun **which** to your clause and make it non-restrictive, but it will look strange in this role, especially in a legal text:

> Your use of the Services, which we provide, constitutes the subject-matter of the contract. ("Oh, and by the way, it's we who provide these services")